# CDC with Snowflake Secure views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a way I can enable streams on views to allow me to track what has changed.

**Example Scenario:**
Handling PII data with secure views, by creating two views per table, e.g. the ORDERS table has customer details and order summary, the views created are : vw_Orders & vw_Orders_PII.

**How can the downstream process that should not have access to PII data identify records that have changed?**

One option is the modifieddate, however trying to avoid that to utilise the inbuilt streams feature for efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a stream off a view.

(Since this was answered, this is now out of date. It is possible to use streams on views: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stream.html#usage-notes)

you can put a stream on each of the tables making up the view. You can then create a view off of those streams to hide the PII columns. Not sure if this will get you what you need, but hopefully it gives some ideas:

```
create or replace table a (id int, col1 string, PII string);
create or replace table b (id int, col1 string, PII string);

create or replace stream a_stream on table a;
create or replace stream b_stream on table b;

insert into a values (1, 'Non-PII data in table a', 'PII data');
insert into b values (1, 'Non-PII data in table b', 'PII data');

create or replace view stream_view as
select a.ID                 A_ID,
       a.col1               A_COL1,
       b.col1               B_COL1,
       a.METADATA$ACTION    A_METADATA$ACTION,
       a.METADATA$ISUPDATE  A_METADATA$ISUPDATE,
       a.METADATA$ROW_ID    A_METADATA$ROW_ID,
       b.METADATA$ACTION    B_METADATA$ACTION,
       b.METADATA$ISUPDATE  B_METADATA$ISUPDATE,
       b.METADATA$ROW_ID    B_METADATA$ROW_ID
from a_stream A left join b_stream B 
    on a.id = b.id;
    
select * from stream_view;
```

Comment: Thanks Greg, this works great and solves my problem!!

Comment: Dharma - can you mark this answer as the solution? :)